# Cannot understand PostgreSQL Documentation regarding FOR UPDATE row lock

Tags: sql, postgresql

> When a locking clause appears in a sub-SELECT, the rows locked are those returned to the outer query by the sub-query. This might involve fewer rows than inspection of the sub-query alone would suggest, since conditions from the outer query might be used to optimize execution of the sub-query. For example,
>
> `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable FOR UPDATE) ss WHERE col1 = 5;`
> will lock only rows having col1 = 5, even though that condition is not textually within the sub-query.

Can somebody please help me understand the sentence "This might involve fewer rows than inspection of the sub-query alone would suggest, since conditions from the outer query might be used to optimize execution of the sub-query"?

My understanding is that "the rows locked are those returned to the outer query by the sub-query" so whatever subquery return (in this case all rows), those rows must be lock? Why is it that only co1 = 5 is locked

Answer (score 1):

The subquery only locks rows if the subquery actually runs.

Sometimes PostgreSQL might notice that it can skip over execution of parts of the outer query to save time, without affecting the rows returned by the query.

For an oversimplified example, if you write

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (SELECT ... FROM othertable WHERE ... FOR UPDATE) = 1 AND FALSE;
```

PostgreSQL would be free to lock zero rows from `othertable`, because it can prove that skipping execution of the subquery will not affect the results of the query.

In the example in the docs, the point is that if there are rows with col1 = 4, col1 = 6, etc, those rows *may not* be locked, because PostgreSQL could check the condition `col1 = 5` and decide the row doesn't match before it executes the subquery. But the corollary is that they also *may* be locked, if PostgreSQL decides to execute the subquery first.

I strongly advise you to do explicit row locking as part of a CTE or similar, where it's entirely clear what will be executed and what won't.

Comment: Thank you! I would not have figure out this implicit optimization, how else can i do explicit locking for rows? I dont want to do table locking

Comment: @Zanko You can do it this way, it's fine. You just need to understand the implications about which rows are locked. Sometimes it's useful to use a CTE (`WITH` query) to split it up into steps that you can control the execution of.